# how many combinations needed to decode AES-256 key?

Tags: encryption

How many combinations needed to decode AES-256 key?

I am not very good in cryptography but I think its something like Combination 256 of 16. Its not too much.

IF use all worlds computing power what time needed for decoding?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you were simply brute forcing every possible key, there would be 2^256 keys you need to try. You'd expect to find it after going through (on average) half of the keys, so average expected number of attempts would be 2^255. This is a Really Big Number. If every atom on earth ([about 1.3 * 10^50 atoms](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_many_atoms_are_there_on_earth)) was a computer that could try ten billion keys a second, it would still take about 2.84 billion years. Brute-forcing is simply not possible - you'd need to find a weakness in the algorithm that lets you take a short-cut here.

Comment: Why 2^256 ? isn't key a hexadecimal number?

Comment: Nope. The key is a binary blob of 256 bits. It's common to represent it as hex just because it's hard to type characters like `\0`, but there's nothing fundamentally hexadecimal about it. That said, even in hex, `16^16` (number of possible keys consisting of 16 hexadecimal characters) = `2^256` (number of possible keys consisting of 256 bits).

Comment: hm i calculated 2^256 = 1*e77 how can it take then 7,6e85 years? I guess we calculated something wrong.

Comment: Also if one operation takes plank time it takes 3600*24*365/10^-44 so in one year it is possible to make 3*e51 operations. It will take only e26 years. If use one billion computers it will take e17 years. What is still impossible to break )

Comment: but if use aes-128 then in one year you can make e13 more operations then needed. So it can be broken faster then for one year. If one operation is performed in plank time. Though its not possible now in near future it can become possible. So to protect very important data we need to use at least 256 algorithms.

Comment: Lets use NIST & ECRYPT2 recommendations instead, eg found on keylength.com.

Comment: If you regard the key as a hexadecimal number, you have 64 digits, so the number of keys is 16^64 which is the same as 2^256.

Answer (score 2):

2^256=16^64=115,792,089,237,316,195,423,570,985,008,687,907,853,269,984,665,640,564,039,457,584,007,913,129,639,936.

According to [mathcats.com](http://www.mathcats.com/explore/reallybignumbers.html), it's written as:

One hundred fifteen quattuorvigintillion, 
seven hundred ninety-two trevigintillion, 
eighty-nine duovigintillion, 
two hundred thirty-seven unvigintillion, 
three hundred sixteen vigintillion, 
one hundred ninety-five novemdecillion, 
four hundred twenty-three octodecillion, 
five hundred seventy septendecillion, 
nine hundred eighty-five sexdecillion, 
eight quindecillion, 
six hundred eighty-seven quattuordecillion, 
nine hundred seven tredecillion, 
eight hundred fifty-three duodecillion, 
two hundred sixty-nine undecillion, 
nine hundred eighty-four decillion, 
six hundred sixty-five nonillion, 
six hundred forty octillion, 
five hundred sixty-four septillion, 
thirty-nine sextillion, 
four hundred fifty-seven quintillion, 
five hundred eighty-four quadrillion, 
seven trillion, 
nine hundred thirteen billion, 
one hundred twenty-nine million, 
six hundred thirty-nine thousand, 
nine hundred thirty-six!

Comment: Please provide the **full** url to your source

Comment: I added it.  It's an online really big number to text converter.  I also use https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm to get the number. And in case you're wondering, 2048 bit encryption has 2^2048 possibilities, so it looks like: thirty-two 204-illion (too big!!), 
three hundred seventeen 203-illion (too big!!), 
six 202-illion (too big!!), 
seventy-one 201-illion (too big!!)... etc. (Mathcats doesn't work after centillion) https://www.quora.com/What-number-comes-after-Centillion